# Building apache Kafka

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-kafka

I am trying to build Kafka with Scala 2.10.1. I tried following steps given on Git-hub. At the end it generates a Jar in Target directory, however that Jar is empty and the size is 5kb. Am I missing something here ? I am totally new to SBT.

1) ./sbt update
2) ./sbt package
3) ./sbt assembly-package-dependency

To build for a particular version of Scala (either 2.8.0, 2.8.2, 2.9.1, 2.9.2 or 2.10.1), change step 2 above to: 2. ./sbt "++2.8.0 package"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Kafka jar is located in `core/target/scala-2.10/` directory, and dependencies are in the Ivy cache.

Execute `./sbt release-zip` to get an archive in `target/RELEASE/` with all dependencies and shell scripts packaged.

To build release for a particular Scala version, add version param to the build command:

```
./sbt "++2.10.1 release-zip"
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That works. However, ./sbt release-zip exports archive for scala 2.8 which is default. I built Kafka with 2.10. How should I get archive for Scala 2.10?

Comment: In Kafka 0.8.1 they have moved to the Gradle build tool. The instructions are at https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.8.1/README.md